# REST access denied to vote

Tags: users, rating

I have enabled the following modules on the site: VotingApi, Like&DisLike, Rest, RestUI and other depending modules

I use POSTMAN as my client and write my GET and POST request from it.

I have Resource "Content" and "Vote" enabled with all methods, auth and format.

I have created a REST Export view of the content and vote.

When I try to GET and/or POST to create a content I was able to do it successfully.

But when I use POST to vote on the content, I get a 403 response. I have provided a correct credentials on it, with header same as content has.

In Drupal browser logs, it says:

```
Type    access denied
Date    Friday, June 30, 2017 - 07:12
User    Anonymous (not verified)
Location    http://example.com/entity/vote
Referrer    
Message /entity/vote
Severity    Warning
Hostname    172.17.0.1
```

Here is my POST request:

```
{
    "type": [
        {
            "target_id": "like"
        }
    ],
    "entity_id": [
        {
            "target_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "value": [
        {
            "value": 1
        }
    ],
    "value_type": [
        {
            "value": "points"
        }
    ],
    "user_id": [
        {
            "target_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probally haven't added permissions for anonymous user to do a GET/POST request to the given endpoint. Go to permissions, search for rest and enable "Access GET on [rest resource]" (Access GET on Node rest resource resource)